# Are there LPG gas stations for cars travelling between Sydney and Melbourne?

Tags: australia, automobiles, sydney, melbourne

We are planning a trip in a dedicated LPG ford  and just wanted to know if there are enough gas stations along the way between Sydney and Melbourne

Comment: Should be no problemo. Cairns to Broome might be a different story though.

Comment: I reckon you'll be fine doing Cairns to Broome as well.  Looking at the combination of [BP's sites](http://www.bp.com/retail/iframe.do?categoryId=9038098&contentId=7069965) and [Shell's sites](http://www.shell.com.au/products-services/on-the-road/fuel-finder/ausfinder.html) there's a fairly regular spread and the ones I checked all had LPG.

Answer (score 5):

You should be fine - [people have done it in the past, even driving Melbourne to Gold Coast](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1596422), with plenty of stops.

However, if you want to be certain, the Shell gas stations have an online [Fuel finder](http://www.shell.com.au/products-services/on-the-road/fuel-finder/ausfinder.html) site to locate the different types of stations, as well as [iPhone and Android apps](http://www.shell.com.au/products-services/on-the-road/fuel-finder/mobile.html).  And they're certainly not the only fuel company in Australia.

Answer (score 4):

You will have absolutely no issues.  By far the majority of Sydney and Melbourne petrol stations have LPG, especially the chains, so assuming your car has 400 kilometres range ([600 km was not unreasonable five years ago](http://www.carsguide.com.au/tools-and-advice/hints-and-tips/the_lowdown_on_lpg)) on a full tank minimum, you can make the following stops without even going out of your way:

- Sydney
- [Gundagai](http://www.colesexpress.com.au/store-locator.aspx?locatorSearch=2722,%20Gundagai%20NSW) (400 km)
- [Albury/Wodonga](http://www.colesexpress.com.au/store-locator.aspx?locatorSearch=Albury) (200 km)
- Melbourne (350 km)

Comment: +1.  The Hume Highway is a major thoroughfare and even in the quieter middle stretches it's rarely more than 50 km between large branded petrol stations, which almost always sell LPG.